# Append values to vector by for loop not working

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, append

Basically, I want to take elements in vector k, but not in vector l, and append them to vector h.
Here is my code using for loop:

```
k=c(1,2,3,5,8,9)
l=c(3,5,7,5,7,9,64)
h=c()

for (i in k) {
  if (!(i %in% l)) {
    print(i)
    append(h,i)
  }
}
```

After run the code, vector h does not change at all, but it should be c(1,2,8).

Comment: Append function does not work. But I have found simple working alternative: h = c(h,i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use R's vectorization to your advantage.  You could just do

```
k[!k %in% l]
# [1] 1 2 8
```

Answer (score 9):

With `append` you need to assign the result

```
k=c(1,2,3,5,8,9)
l=c(3,5,7,5,7,9,64)
h=c()

for (i in k) {
  if (!(i %in% l)) {
    print(i)
    h<-append(h,i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the answer from @RichardScriven is totally better