# Why does the append() function return NULL values

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to create a column named 'ypc' based on the calculation of the values in a specific column. The way I decided to do this is to write a function (code below).

```
Y2Y_Calculator <- function(x){
  ypc <- c()
  input_country <- date_formatted %>% filter(Country == x)
  yearly_change <- for (i in 1:nrow(input_country)) {
    changes <- (input_country[i+4,3]-input_country[i,3])/input_country[i,3]
    value <- changes[1,1]
    append(change_index, ypc)
  }
mutate(date_formatted, change_index)
}
```

In this function, I wrote a for loop to calculate the desired numbers and it ("changes") returned [multiple 1x1 data frames with a single value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7zhw.png). My goal here is to extract the [values in the data frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbh2A.png) and put them in a single **vector "ypc"** with **append()** that can be later used with the mutate() function. However, when I ran the code, "ypc" ultimately returned multiple  [*NULL* values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwWPY.png). Can someone please help me solve the problem and explain which step is wrong to lead to the undesired result of the vector "ypc"?

Comment: It’s null because `ypc <- c()`?

Comment: I am not pretty sure. But I have tried to append() the ypc, I just don't know why append() seems to fail here. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I think I have figured out the problem. The reason it returned NULL values is because I failed to assign the result back to "ypc". I have read this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963493/append-values-to-vector-by-for-loop-not-working to get my question answered. Thank you for your help!